# Strange output of a Graph with void pointers

Tags: c, debugging, graph, codeblocks, void-pointers

I'm trying to build a program that can work on Graphs with either an adjacency List or Matrix, in order to do so the teacher taught us to declare the adjacencies as a void *, in order to cast it as a List or Matrix.

With the following code i get this output:
[image]

As you can see there're strange things hanging out in B node.

If i try to debug with CodeBlocks the debugger gives a `Segmentation Fault` in `appendNodeList` at `if (L->target != target) {..`

I think that there's a problem with the dynamic allocation in `initGraphList` but I don't know how to fix it.

What do you think is the problem here? Is it the allocation? If yes, how can I fix it?
Thanks in advance for the help!

**Code:**

main.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "Graph.h"

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    Graph G = NULL;
    G = initGraphList(3);
    addEdgeList(G, 0, 1, 1);
    addEdgeList(G, 0, 2, 2);
    addEdgeList(G, 1, 0, 3);
    addEdgeList(G, 1, 2, 4);
    addEdgeList(G, 2, 0, 5);
    addEdgeList(G, 2, 1, 6);
    printGraphList(G);
    return 0;
}
```

Graph.h

```
#include "List.h"

struct TGraph {
    void **adj;
    int nodes_count;
};

typedef struct TGraph *Graph;

typedef struct AdjList{
    List *nodes;
}AdjList;

Graph initGraphList(int);
void printGraphList(Graph G);
void addEdgeList(Graph G, int source, int target, float peso);
```

Graph.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "Graph.h"

Graph initGraphList(int nodes_count){
    Graph G = (Graph)malloc(sizeof(struct TGraph));
    G->adj = malloc(sizeof(AdjList));
    G->nodes_count = nodes_count;
    ((AdjList *)(G->adj))->nodes = malloc(nodes_count * sizeof(List));
    return G;
}

void printGraphList(Graph G) {
    if (G != NULL) {
        int i;
        for(i = 0; i < G->nodes_count; i++) {
            printf("%c -> ", i + 'A');  //I use this in order to print out the nodes as A,B,C,.. instead of 0,1,2,...
            printList(((AdjList *)(G->adj))->nodes[i]);
            puts("\n");
        }
    }
}

void addEdgeList(Graph G, int source, int target, float peso){
    if(G != NULL){
        if(source != target){
            if(source < G->nodes_count){
                if(target < G->nodes_count)
                    ((AdjList*)(G->adj))->nodes[source]= appendNodeList(((AdjList*)(G->adj))->nodes[source], target, peso);
                else
                    fprintf(stderr, "Il nodo %d non e' compreso nel grafo\n", target);
            }else
                fprintf(stderr, "Il nodo %d non e' compreso nel grafo\n", source);
        }else
            fprintf(stderr, "Non e' possibile inserire un arco che punta allo stesso nodo\n");
    }else
        fprintf(stderr, "Grafo invalido\n");
}
```

List.h

```
struct TList {
    char target;
    float peso;
    struct TList* next;
};

List initNodeList(int info, float peso);
List appendNodeList(List L, int target, float peso);
void printList(List L);
```

List.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "List.h"

List initNodeList(int info, float peso) {
    List L = malloc(sizeof(struct TList));
    L->target = info;
    L->peso = peso;
    L->next = NULL;
    return L;
}

List appendNodeList(List L, int target, float peso) {
    if (L != NULL) {
        if (L->target != target) {
            L->next = appendNodeList(L->next, target, peso);
        }
    } else {
        L = initNodeList(target, peso);
    }
    return L;
}

void printList(List L) {
    if (L != NULL) {
        printf(" %c(%f), ", L->target + 'A', L->peso);
        printList(L->next);
    }
}
```

Comment: You mind creating an [___MCVE___](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Aside: when declaring a pointer type, it makes the code more readable if the type name and subsequent variables of that type use a style Hungarian notation to tip off the reader, such as `typedef struct TGraph *pGraph;`

Comment: @SouravGhosh
It should be a MCVE now, I removed the free functions and added the headers to include and merged the Graph.h with AdjList.h.

@WeatherVane I think i did that with `typedef struct TGraph *Graph;` or maybe i dont get you're saying.

Comment: The post posted code does not compile.  Either the complete code is not posted or the code has never been compiled, because there is no definition of `List`,   I suspect the file `list.h` is missing a `typedef` for `List`.

Comment: the header files are all missing the 'include guard'  A 'include guard'  can be either `pragma once` or (IMO: preferred) `#ifndef UNIQUE_NAME / #define UNIQUE_NAME .....#endif // UNIQUE_NAME`

Comment: suggest inserting this: `typedef struct TList *List;` into the list.h file

Comment: the `main()` function fails to cleanly compile. there are two unused parameters: `argc` and `argv[]`. suggest using `int main( void )` for the signature

Comment: when ever calling `malloc()` always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.   in C, do not cast the returned value from `malloc()` as the type is already `void*` so can be assigned to any other pointer.  Casting just clutters the code, making it more difficult to understand, debug, maintain.

Comment: the posted code contains LOTS of calls to malloc, but never passes any of that allocated memory to `free()`.  This result sin a massive memory leak

Comment: @user3629249
Sorry, i forgot to include the `List` in `List.h`, as for the free i didn't include it in order to keep the program short.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you forgot to initialize your array of pointers with NULL. That was the main fault I found in your code.

If you make any pointer typedef avoid misleading names (for example add postfix 
'Ptr' to typename)

```
typedef struct TList {
    char target;
    float peso;
    struct TList* next;
} *TListPtr;

typedef struct TAdjList{
    TListPtr *nodes;
} *TAdjListPtr;
```

There is no need of `void **adj`. `TAdjListPtr *adj` does what you want

```
typedef struct TGraph {
    TAdjListPtr adj;
    int nodes_count;
} *TGraphPtr;

TListPtr initNodeList(int info, float peso) {
    TListPtr L = malloc(sizeof(struct TList));
    L->target = info;
    L->peso = peso;
    L->next = NULL;
    return L;
}

TListPtr appendNodeList(TListPtr L, int target, float peso) {
    if (L != NULL) {
        if (L->target != target) {
            L->next = appendNodeList(L->next, target, peso);
        }
    } else {
        L = initNodeList(target, peso);
    }
    return L;
}

void printList(TListPtr L) {
    if (L != NULL) {
        printf(" %c(%f), ", L->target + 'A', L->peso);
        printList(L->next);
    }
}
```

You have to initialize your array of pointer with NULL. Use `memset` for this.

```
TGraphPtr initGraphList(int nodes_count){
    TGraphPtr G = malloc(sizeof(struct TGraph));
    G->adj = malloc(sizeof(TAdjList));
    G->nodes_count = nodes_count;
    G->adj->nodes = (TListPtr*)malloc(nodes_count * sizeof(TListPtr));
    memset( G->adj->nodes, 0, nodes_count * sizeof( TListPtr ) );
    return G;
}

void printGraphList(TGraphPtr G) {
    if (G != NULL) {
        int i;
        for(i = 0; i < G->nodes_count; i++) {
            printf("%c -> ", i + 'A');  //I use this in order to print out the nodes as A,B,C,.. instead of 0,1,2,...
            printList(G->adj->nodes[i] );
            puts("\n");
        }
    }
}

void addEdgeList(TGraphPtr G, int source, int target, float peso){
    if(G != NULL){
        if(source != target){
            if(source < G->nodes_count){
                if(target < G->nodes_count)
                    G->adj->nodes[source] = appendNodeList(G->adj->nodes[source], target, peso);
                else
                    fprintf(stderr, "Il nodo %d non e' compreso nel grafo\n", target);
            }else
                fprintf(stderr, "Il nodo %d non e' compreso nel grafo\n", source);
        }else
            fprintf(stderr, "Non e' possibile inserire un arco che punta allo stesso nodo\n");
    }else
        fprintf(stderr, "Grafo invalido\n");
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That memset was indeed all I needed in order to get it to work properly!

Anyway I still need to use the `void **` because i have to treat the adiacensies either as a List and as a Matrix.

The matrix structure is this:

`typedef struct AdjMatrix{
    float **nodes;
}AdjMatrix`

So i still need to cast the `void **` as an `AdjMatrix` or as a `AdjList`.

Answer (score 0):

after eliminating the complier errors.and warnings

but without adding the error checking, this is the result.

Note:: I have not checked this code for any undefined behaviour

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


struct TList
{
    size_t target;
    float peso;
    struct TList* next;
};
//typedef struct TList * List;

struct TList * initNodeList(size_t info, float peso);
struct TList * appendNodeList(struct TList * L, size_t target, float peso);
void printList(struct TList * L);

struct TGraph
{
    struct TList **nodes;
    size_t nodes_count;
};

//typedef struct TGraph * Graph;



struct TGraph * initGraphList(size_t);
void printGraphList(struct TGraph *);
void addEdgeList(struct TGraph *, size_t, size_t, float);



int main( void )
{
    struct TGraph * G = NULL;
    G = initGraphList(3);
    addEdgeList(G, 0, 1, 1);
    addEdgeList(G, 0, 2, 2);
    addEdgeList(G, 1, 0, 3);
    addEdgeList(G, 1, 2, 4);
    addEdgeList(G, 2, 0, 5);
    addEdgeList(G, 2, 1, 6);
    printGraphList(G);
    return 0;
} // end function: main


struct TList * initNodeList(size_t info, float peso)
{
    struct TList * L = malloc(sizeof(struct TList));
    L->target = info;
    L->peso = peso;
    L->next = NULL;
    return L;
} // end function: initNodeList


struct TList * appendNodeList(struct TList * L, size_t target, float peso)
{
    if (L != NULL)
    {
        if (L->target != target)
        {
            L->next = appendNodeList(L->next, target, peso);
        }
    }

    else
    {
        L = initNodeList(target, peso);
    }
    return L;
} // end function: appendNodeList


void printList(struct TList * L)
{
    if (L != NULL)
    {
        printf(" %c(%f), ", (char)L->target + 'A', L->peso);
        printList(L->next);
    }
} // end function: printList


struct TGraph * initGraphList(size_t nodes_count)
{
    struct TGraph * G = malloc(sizeof(struct TGraph));
    G->nodes_count = nodes_count;
    G->nodes = malloc(nodes_count * sizeof(struct TList *));
    return G;
} // end function: initGraphList


void printGraphList(struct TGraph * G)
{
    if (G != NULL)
    {
        for(size_t i = 0; i < G->nodes_count; i++)
        {
            printf("%c -> ", (char)i + 'A');  //I use this in order to print out the nodes as A,B,C,.. instead of 0,1,2,...
            printList(G->nodes[i]);
            puts("\n");
        }
    }
}

void addEdgeList(struct TGraph * G, size_t source, size_t target, float peso)
{
    if(G != NULL)
    {
        if(source != target)
        {
            if(source < G->nodes_count)
            {
                if(target < G->nodes_count)
                    G->nodes[source]= appendNodeList(G->nodes[source], target, peso);
                else
                    fprintf(stderr, "Il nodo %c non e' compreso nel grafo\n", (char)target);
            }

            else
                fprintf(stderr, "Il nodo %c non e' compreso nel grafo\n", (char)source);
        }

        else
            fprintf(stderr, "Non e' possibile inserire un arco che punta allo stesso nodo\n");
    }

    else
        fprintf(stderr, "Grafo invalido\n");
}
```

and the output is:

```
A ->  B(1.000000),  C(2.000000), 

B ->  A(3.000000),  C(4.000000), 

C ->  A(5.000000),  B(6.000000),
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help but i need to treat the adiacensies either as a List or Matrix, in order to do so i have to declare the adiacensies as a `void **` (At least for what i know and what the teacher taught me) all i was missing from my code was a memset to set NULL the list and it works fine now.

I still thank you for your time and efforts!